# What`s wrong in my query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Can anyone help me figure out why i get an SQL error on this query:

```
SELECT * FROM articles 
       LIMIT $offset, $rowsperpage 
       ORDER BY article_timestamp DESC
```

Thanks in adance!

Comment: Can you please add the error message? And perhaps some surrounding PHP code (how it is used)?

Comment: Could you give us the error message it's showing you? And also what is `$offset` & `$rowsperpage`, try to include all relevant code.

Comment: Almost certainly because $offset or $rowsperpage aren't what you think they are.

Comment: I think LIMIT should be in end?

Comment: Put the LIMIT clause at the end and try again.

Comment: it just an SQL FATAL ERROR

Comment: Which fatal error ? what is the message exactly ?

Comment: @ImaneFateh, take a look at all the answers given. It seems that some people understand exactly what the question is.

Comment: How is this even closed as "unclear what you're asking"? I agree it should be closed but this is such an invalid reason.

Comment: @Gildil Then these people are fortune tellers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `LIMIT` clause at the end of the query.

```
SELECT * FROM articles
ORDER BY article_timestamp DESC
LIMIT $offset, $rowsperpage
```

You must have to follow the **Syntax of MySQL**..

```
SELECT
    [ALL | DISTINCT | DISTINCTROW ]
      [HIGH_PRIORITY]
      [STRAIGHT_JOIN]
      [SQL_SMALL_RESULT] [SQL_BIG_RESULT] [SQL_BUFFER_RESULT]
      [SQL_CACHE | SQL_NO_CACHE] [SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS]
    select_expr [, select_expr ...]
    [FROM table_references
    [WHERE where_condition]
    [GROUP BY {col_name | expr | position}
      [ASC | DESC], ... [WITH ROLLUP]]
    [HAVING where_condition]
    [ORDER BY {col_name | expr | position}
      [ASC | DESC], ...]
    [LIMIT {[offset,] row_count | row_count OFFSET offset}]
    [PROCEDURE procedure_name(argument_list)]
    [INTO OUTFILE 'file_name' export_options
      | INTO DUMPFILE 'file_name'
      | INTO var_name [, var_name]]
    [FOR UPDATE | LOCK IN SHARE MODE]]
```

More Info :- [MySQL SELECT Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html)

Comment: Thanks for the querry order... I didn`t know that it matters. Verry usefull post you got there!

Answer (score 1):

Limit should be in end. It should order first then get limited rows

```
SELECT * FROM articles 
ORDER BY article_timestamp DESC
LIMIT $offset, $rowsperpage
```

Comment: +1 because you answered first, despite the fact that we don't know whether it is the origin of the problem or not ;)

Comment: @ImaneFateh Agreed, there might be other problems in there but thats the only clear problem i could see.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   ARTICLES 
ORDER  BY ARTICLE_TIMESTAMP DESC 
LIMIT  $OFFSET, $ROWSPERPAGE
```